# AngularDart v0.14.0 Error: Type 'xxx' not found in generated typeFactory maps when run pub server

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I test my app on AngularDart v0.14.0 pub server but it has error

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: Type 'CurrencyService' not found in generated typeFactory maps. Is the type's constructor injectable and annotated for injection?
Stack Trace:
#0      GeneratedTypeFactories.parameterKeysFor (package:di/src/reflector_static.dart:26:5)
#1      Binding.bind (package:di/src/module.dart:61:49)
#2      Module.bindByKey (package:di/src/module.dart:136:17)
#3      Module.bind (package:di/src/module.dart:124:14)
#4      CERPModule.CERPModule (http://localhost:8080/index.dart:71:9)
#5      main.<anonymous closure> (http://localhost:8080/index.dart:59:201)
#6      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1082)
#7      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:488)
#8      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:571)
#9      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:331)
#10     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:393)
#11     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#12     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#13     _handleMutation (dart:html:39006)
```

When run in localhost:3030 this error don't occur.

Here is my Module

```dart
class CERPModule extends Module {
...
    bind(CurrencyService);
...
}
```

Here is my CurrencyService

```dart
library cerp_currency_service;

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';


class CurrencyService {
  Http _http;
  CurrencyService (Http this._http);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need to add the `@Injectable` annotation to your `CurrencyService` class.

```dart
@Injectable()
class CurrencyService {
```

Comment: That's right, you need to add the @Injectable annotation - note that the dynamic version of the DI do not requires this annotation. However this code will not work without the annotation when build or served via pub (pub build or pub server). There is a PR pending https://github.com/angular/di.dart/pull/174 that will enforce this annotation when assert mode is enabled in the dynamic version.