# AngularDart v1.0 Uncaught Type "[type]" not found in generated typeFactory maps

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an app that I've primarily built in AngularDart v0.12 that was building into and running in JS just fine, but after upgrading to AngularDart v1.0 and accounting for the breaking changes, it fails to run in JS now after building to it without a problem. When attempting to run in Chrome the console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught Type "QueryService" not found in generated typeFactory maps
```

The following is my pubspec.yaml config:

```
name: ###
author: ###
description: ###
homepage: ###
transformers:
   - angular:
        dart_sdk: "C:/dart/dart-sdk"
        suppressWarnings: false
   - $dart2js:
        suppressWarnings: false
        minify: false
        checked: true
dependencies:
      angular: any
      angular_dart_ui_bootstrap: any
      bootjack: any
      browser: any
      chrome: any
      di: any
      dquery: any
      google_oauth2_client: any
      http_server: any
      inject: any
      js: any
      logging: any
      mock: any
      mongo_dart: any
      route: any
      shadow_dom: any
      shelf: any
      shelf_route: any
      shelf_web_socket: any
      sqljocky: any
      unittest: any
```

The following is my module class:

```
class AppModule extends Module{
  AppModule(){

    /*
     * Services, Routers, and Controller
     */
    bind(QueryService);
    bind(RoutingService);
    bind(RouteInitializerFn, toValue: initRoutes);
    bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false)); 

    /*
     * Components
     */
    bind(Login);
    bind(Dashboard);
    bind(SideNav); 
  }
}
```

The following is the QueryService class:

```
@Injectable()
class QueryService{
    Http _http;
    Scope _scope;

     QueryService(Http this._http, Scope this._scope){
        someFunction();
     }
 }
```

Just to reiterate, this application is working fine when run using the DartVM, but doesn't seem to want to inject the QueryService when built into JS.

Also, I'm aware this may be very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575880/angulardart-v0-14-0-error-type-xxx-not-found-in-generated-typefactory-maps-wh) question, but the solution doesn't appear to have any effect in my case, and the AngularDart version is newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was importing my app's library directly via a relative path in my main.dart file instead of importing it as a package. This caused a duplicate declaration of the library which must have given the transformer some issues. I basically just had to change my import on my main.dart file from

```
import '../library/src/app.dart';
```

to

```
import 'package:myPackage/app.dart'
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Injectable annotation should trigger the generation of the factory.

If it's not may be you are not running the angular transformer ?

You pubspec should list this transformer, ie:

```
name: myApp
dependencies:
  angular: ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"
transformers:
  - angular
```

Comment: I've got the angular transformer included in the pubspec and even have the location of the dart sdk specified for it as well.